# Use an array to fill out a format string

Tags: javascript, string, format

I am trying to take an array and use its values in a format string.

```
var arry = ["1", "2", "3"];
alert("Numbers {0} equal {2} - {1}.".format(arry));
```

Problem is that this gives `Number 1,2,3 equals {2}-{1}.` Instead of the desired result of `Number 1 equals 3 - 2.`. Is there a way to get this result without having to do some kind of for loop?

Comment: And function String.format() looks like?

Comment: `.format()` is a python thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function arrayFormat(str, arr) {
    return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, m1) {
        return (m1 in arr) ? arr[m1] : match;
    });
}
```

This uses [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), with the second argument as a function. It uses each occurrence of a number in brackets as a key, and replaces that occurrence with the value from the array corresponding to that key.

[**See it in action here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/46tL4w41/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String.format = function() {
  var s = arguments[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments[1].length; i++) {       
      var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
      s = s.replace(reg, arguments[1][i]);
  }
  return s;
}
var arry = ["1", "2", "3"];

console.log(String.format("Number {0} equal {2} - {1}.",arry)); //Numbers 1 equal 3 - 2.
console.log(String.format("Number {0} equal {2} - {1}.",'1')); //Numbers 1 equal {2} - {1}.
console.log(String.format("Number {0} equal {2} - {1}.",'12')); //Numbers 1 equal {2} - 2.
console.log(String.format("Number {0} equal {2} - {1}.",'123')); //Numbers 1 equal 3 - 2.
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/enginustun/fzpttbhy/)